# Ajax function doesn't show view included in the controller

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I try that: when clicking on an image a function is executed, this function collects a value and sends it via POST to the controller, this controller collects this data and displays the view. The problem is that everything works  but it doesn't get to show me the view, I stay where I was.

Image that calls the function when clicking:

```
<img onclick="getSubjectPublication(<?php echo $inf->codiAsignaturaDesti; ?>)" id="click" src="/EEmobi/resources/images/click.png"/>
```

Function:

```
function getSubjectPublication(data){
console.log("EntroFuncion");
console.log(data);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "perfil.php/" + "subjectPublications",
    data: {"data":data},
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(t, e) {
        window.alert("Error al intentar visualitzar les publicacions");
    }
})}
```

The function calls this general controller (lib), it collects the sent data and passes it to the specific controller:

```
case 'subjectPublications':
        $controllerName = "SubjectPublicationsController";
        $actionName = "showSubjectPublications";
        $data = $_POST['data'];
        array_push($parameters, $data);
        break;
```

Specific Controller:

```
<?php class SubjectPublicationsController{
function __construct(){

    $this->view = new View();
}

public function showSubjectPublications($parameters){

    require 'models/PublicationsSubjectModel.php';

    $publicationsSubjectModel = new PublicationsSubjectModel();
    $data  = $parameters[0];
    echo "<script>console.log('ENTROFINAL');</script>";
    echo "<script>console.log('. json_encode( $data ) .');</script>";
    $subjectPublications = $publicationsSubjectModel->getPublicationOfSubject($data);

    $route = $this->view->show("PublicationsSubject.php");

    $publicationsSubjectModel->disconnect();

    include ($route);

}}?>
```

The case is that in the console browser it shows me the console.log that I do in the function and the response returns the entire web including the view that I include in the controller (the view that i wanted to show in the browser), but it doesn't show it on the screen, i continue with the same screen and not the one that I included in the controller. What am I doing wrong?
[Browser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i30NY.png)

Comment: The problem is because you're not doing anything with the response from the AJAX request. All you do it log it to the console. Presumably you need to update the DOM...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i think so, but how can i do it? I want that when clicking on the image the other view with the data of the POST I have sent will load. What do I have to put in the success function? I'm pretty new in this

Comment: When you complete a ajax request you generally want to send back a json object. In this case maybe about the image that you clicked. So then you do something with that in your success function e.g alert - or show a popup or something. Look at json_encode to send your data back from your php page https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @RichardHousham thank you so much finally i got it. I missed  $(".panel-body").html(e)! Now it works

Comment: @RichardHousham please leave your comment as an answer so that OP can tag it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you complete a ajax request you generally want to send back a json object. In this case maybe about the image that you clicked. So then you do something with that in your success function e.g alert - or show a popup or something. Look at json_encode to send your data back from your php page [php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)